# nmap for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: nmap, ubuntu-20.04

The command `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.1/24 --disable-arp-ping` on an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS machine and also a windows machine connected to a TP-Link 4g router sometimes works and sometimes does not find all alive hosts, why?

Comment: For this exact command (changing only my subnet) I get a solid report (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) on a regular wireless router. Check all the devices you have on the 4G router with ping and see if that sheds light.

Comment: All the devices response to ping but nmap sometimes doesn't show devices on the report.

Comment: I am not sure, except I think it might be related to the 4G router. I have NMAP version 7.91 .

Comment: I've Nmap 7.80.

Comment: There is the same problem on a Windows machine using Nmap version 7.91.

Comment: It has to be with the 4G router you have. Can you update the firmware for it?

Comment: I've already updated the firmware to the latest version.

Comment: You are probably at the end of the road with the 4G device. I really do not think it is a Windows, Linux, or nmap issue unfortunately.

Comment: What do you mean with "at the end of the road"?

Comment: If you have the latest firmware and Operating Software plus nmap does not work right, you probably need a different router. As I noted at the beginning, this all works on my own wireless router.

Comment: You should respond without looking at the interests of the sysadmins.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I have replaced routers of my own that did not work properly with the devices I had.